# C# Dependency Injection and the Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm using [Munq](http://munq.codeplex.com/) as the DI container in a MVC3 project. I have a service layer that retrieves a DTO from a repository. Depending on a property in that DTO I need to use one of two strategies to perform calculations on the DTO. I can register a named type in the container e.g.

```
Container.Register<ICalculation>("Type1", c => new Type1Calculation);
Container.Register<ICalculation>("Type2", c => new Type2Calculation);
```

Then I can refer directly to the container when trying to instantiate the appropriate strategy e.g.

```
var calc = Container.Resolve<ICalculation>(dto.ServiceType);
```

But this leaves me with a dependency on the container itself with the associated coupling and testing issues. What do I need to pass into the service constructor that would allow me to get the correct calculation but without the dependency on the container? Should I pass in a factory instead so the dependency is in the factory and not in the service class?

Comment: As an update to the above, I am currently using and recommend SimpleInjector https://simpleinjector.org for DI. Some excellent background information is available at https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the Munq solution to this. First the factory which includes the *IDependencyResolver* interface to allow the factory to use the container to resolve dependencies in the factory method:

```
public class CalculationFactory
{
    private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;
    public CalculationFactory(IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        ThrowIfNullArgument(resolver, "resolver", typeof(IDependencyResolver));
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public static ICalculation CreateCalculator(int serviceType)
    {
        switch (serviceType)
        {
            case 1: return _resolver.Resolve<ICalculation>("Type1");
            case 2: return _resolver.Resolve<ICalculation>("Type2");
            default: return _resolver.Resolve<ICalculation>("InvalidType");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Global.asax.cs register the appropriate interfaces/classes, passing in the container to the factory. So now I can set up my tests and the only extra dependency is *IDependencyResolver* within the factory:

```
ioc.Register(c => new CalculationFactory(c));
ioc.Register<ICalculation>("Type1", c => c.Resolve<Type1Calculation>());
ioc.Register<ICalculation>("Type2", c => c.Resolve<Type2Calculation>());
ioc.Register<ICalculation>("InvalidType", c => c.Resolve<InvalidCalculation>());
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about Munq, but Autofac allows you to pass around `Func`s, so that you can skip all factories altogether:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Func<string, IBar> barFactory) { }
}
```

Check if Munq allows for such behavior.

Otherwise -- yes, you'll have to resort to hand-written factories to provide yet another level of indirection.

Comment: How does this work in Autofac? You're passing a Func to the constructor which in your example is a factory returning IBar. Is Foo the service class and it has a Func to resolve in my case the calculation? How is this wired up in the Autofac container?

Comment: @David See http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/ and http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes. You don't need to do anything special - almost everything is done by Autofac itself.

Comment: Thanks Anton but I'm still not entirely sure how this "skip[s] all factories altogether". Isn't your Func a factory? How is this better than declaring a factory class and injecting that in the constructor? Can you provide an example of barFactory Func?